# EclipseFP debugger doesnot stop on breakpoints

Tags: eclipse, haskell

I set breakpoints in the source files, when run the Main module in debug mode, there is non-stop in the breakpoints! Am I missing something?

I also tried the tiny little toy example:

```
module Main where

import qualified Data.Set as S

test :: Int -> String
test num = show num

main::IO()
main = do                                                                            
   print $ test 2
```

break points set before `test num` and `print $ test 2`, neither place works

Comment: Share your code and where you're setting the breakpoints.  It's possible that code you think is being evaluated isn't.

Comment: See edited version of the question. (The original project source code is a lot (which is why I tried to use eclipseFP hoping for easy debugging). So I did the tiny little example, which also does not work.)

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that you are setting the wrong kind of breakpoint? Haskell breakpoints seem to be set with the "Toggle breakpoint" command. You have to be in the Haskell or Debug perspective for this command to be enabled.

In my case, I accidentally used the "Add breakpoint" command which sets a Python breakpoint.